# Passing array from JavaScript to PHP without losing code functionality

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Using this piece of code I can list all the file URLs inside the `Folder_A` and `Folder_B` and `Folder_C` :

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()){

    $length = count($directories);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents($path, $results);
        } else {
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    }

    return $results;
}


$directories = array("Folder_A", "Folder_B","Folder_C");

echo json_encode(getDirContents($directories));
```

And using the JavaScript code below we can log them in the console (And have access to them via javascript):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../test.php',
            data: 'id=testdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            },
        });
});
```

I just want one simple thing that I can't find a solution by myself:

How can I define the Folders inside javascript instead of having them in PHP?

I mean instead of having this inside PHP code:

```
$directories = array("Folder_A", "Folder_B","Folder_C");
```

I want to have this in Javascript:

```
let directories = [ "Folder_A", "Folder_B","Folder_C"];
```

And return the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the directories as part of the `data:` parameter.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    let directories = [ "Folder_A", "Folder_B","Folder_C"];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../test.php',
        data: {id: "testdata", directories: directories},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
    });
});
```

Then in PHP you can use `$_POST['directories']` to get the array:

```
echo json_encode(getDirContents($_POST['directories']));
```

Comment: I'm not sure why. Check the Network tab of the console to see what's being sent and received.

Comment: I think space causes the problem, If I have `Folder A` the code doesn't work...if I have `Folder_A` code works fine?!!